# Why can't I do this using swift conditionally compiling?

Tags: swift, multiplatform

Compiler will show mistakes when I do this:

```
#if os(iOS)
class AView: UIView {
#else
class AView: NSView {
#endif
    
}
```

Why can't I do this?

Does it have any methods to do this thing?

Comment: Use a `typealias`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional compiling with a `typealias` instead:

```swift
#if os(iOS)
typealias ParentView = UIView
#else
typealias ParentView = NSView
#endif

class AView: ParentView {}
```

Then you'll be able to extend that type alias.

[Playground](https://swiftfiddle.com/xoyl7xdl6nd5rl4sl6sstggvja)